# Updating database value with button

Tags: javascript, php, sql

```
<?php 
include ('session.php'); 

$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "" , "log_database"); 
$question_id = rand(1,2);
$query = "SELECT * FROM questions WHERE id='$question_id' "; 
$query_run = mysqli_query($connection,$query); 
$query_row = mysqli_num_rows($query_run); 

if ($query_row==1) { 
    foreach ($query_run as $row ) { 
        $option1 = $row['option1']; 
        $option2 = $row['option2']; 
        $money = $row['money'];
        $option1_clicked = $row['option1_clicked'];
        $option2_clicked = $row['option1_clicked'];
        $id_question = $row['id'];
    } 
} 

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Game</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="game.css"> </head>

<body>

    <div id="content_div">
        <img id="title_img" src="wealthypinguin.png">
    </div>

    <div id="question_div">
        <span id="question">
            <?php echo $username; ?>, <br> for <span id="money">€ <?php echo $money; ?></span>,
        <br>would you rather...</span>
    </div>

    <div id="buttons_div">
        <button onclick="addOption1()" id="button1">
            <?php echo $option1; ?>
        </button>
        <br>
        <button onclick="addOption2()" id="button2">
            <?php echo $option2; ?>
        </button>
        <br>
        <button id="button3">
            Keep your money
        </button>
    </div>

</body>

    <script>
        function addOption1() {
            <?php 
                $option1_clicked = $option1_clicked + 1; 
                $queryOption1 = "UPDATE `questions` SET `option1_clicked` = '$option1_clicked' WHERE id='$question_id'";
                $query_run_option1 = mysqli_query($connection,$queryOption1);
            ?>
        }

        function addOption2() {
            <?php 
                $option2_clicked = $option2_clicked + 1; 
                $queryOption2 = "UPDATE `questions` SET `option2_clicked` = '$option2_clicked' WHERE id='$question_id'";
                $query_run_option2 = mysqli_query($connection,$queryOption2);  
            ?>
        }
    </script>

</html>
```

What I want to achieve that when my button1 is clicked, my php variable $option1_clicked is raised by one and the new value is updated in my database.
When I click button2 the same result.

The problem is when I click one of them, the value is updated but it automatically updates both values($option1_clicked, $option2_clicked) to the same value.
So when option1_clicked goes from 6 to 7, option2_clicked gets also the value 7.

Comment: you forgot to add `+1 to the update column; that's where it should be and not before. That is probably failing you; check for errors.

Comment: btw; you should be using ajax for this, why are you using PHP inside JS like that?

Comment: Cause I don't know how to use ajax

Comment: there are a lot of good tutorials out there. One for instance is by one of Stack's members http://jayblanchard.net/basics_of_jquery_ajax.html

Comment: The proper way to do this is with ajax? Ok i'll take a look a the tutorial, thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

Ajax is the best way to do that.
Have a look to that:
https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp

You will be able to send a POST or GET query to a file (often a PHP file) without leave the current web page.

It's very useful, very plaisant for the users (You can create good and fluid User Interfaces), and quite simple.